# How do you make normally hostile mobs not hostile?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a place where nether mobs are friends but I don't know how to. How do I make a mob friendly? (I'm making the map in Creative mode.)

Comment: That sounds like the opposite of what they're trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve friendly effect by setting base of [**`generic.followRange`**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attributes#Attributes_Available_on_All_Living_Entities) attribute of a hostile mob to **`0`**. However doing so will completely disable targetting & tracking ability of a said mob. For example, here's the command to summon *friendly blaze* using this method:

```
/summon Blaze ~ ~1 ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.followRange,Base:0}]}
```

Comment: You can change the follow range, but I would like some way to make the mob hostile to other mobs as well. Like how snowmen and blazes hate each other. Make it passive to you, and you now have a creeper pet! I have no clue if this is possible, but if you could stick the wolf code in a zombie, that would be great.

Comment: @user151259 I think that's possible with scoreboard teams, unfortunately my connection is poor where I am now, so you'll have to search it up yourself.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry but the only way to do this is by using a mod, you can't do that in normal minecraft without being constantly on creative mode.
I recommend you using a mod called Single Player Commands (Link on the bottom). There just use the command "mobdamage" (without quotation marks).

Mod link on the minecraft forum: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272348-single-player-commands-v4-9-official-download-spc

Example: