# Is there a command to stop individual mobs from spawning in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to be able to play survival mode on 1.8.0(with mods) without hostile mobs spawning but with hunger going down. Basically, I want the mobs to act like peaceful mode, but everything else to act like normal mode.

Answer (score 4):

Found on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#gamerule):

> `doMobSpawning` — Whether mobs should naturally spawn

=> `/gamerule doMobSpawning false`

There is no command to disable spawning of a specific mob, nor all hostiles one; you might achieve your result with some server configuration.

---

[Minecraft peaceful mode: spawn hostile mobs, give them creative mode AI](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282247/minecraft-peaceful-mode-spawn-hostile-mobs-give-them-creative-mode-ai?rq=1)

The answer to this question might be useful to you though.

Comment: I am not looking for a generic command - I still want animals that are not normally hostile(sheep cows pigs ocelots etc). I would like to know if there is a command for each mob so I can choose which ones can and can't spawn.

Comment: Okay, I get you – your question was a bit unclear ;)

Comment: I don't think this is feasible with just commands then.

Answer (score 2):

It's not strictly ideal, but you could have a group of repeating commandblocks (1 for each mob to block) either setting the mob's AI to false (so they won't move/attack), or straight up killing them.  If you didn't want the drops, you could tp them to some negative y-value such that they despawn before they die.

For example, stopping all Creepers from moving and attacking:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Creeper] {NoAI:1}
```

Also, "killing" all zombies:

```
/tp @e[type=Zombie] ~ -500 ~
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on 1.8 though, would it?

Comment: @Skye I believe it would.There were some bugs in 1.8 with it if I remember (like NoAI also affecting gravity), but I'm sure if that doesn't also work you could apply a low (0) follow range to them.  See the link in Ealhad's answer for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something similar. It won't stop mobs from spawning but the second they spawn they will die.

You first give yourself a command block. Then, type this command:

```
/kill @e[type=zombie]
```

This example will kill zombies.

Set the command block to repeat and always active.

You can type any mob name in place of the word `zombie` but you have to individually put in a command block for each mob.